# What is the best way to duplicate a row in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of data and I'd like to duplicate a row when an user click on the copy button.
Example:
This is the current list:

[image]

If an user click on user 02 copy button, this row should duplicate (and persist on database) like that:

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

I hope that I was clear.

Tks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dup` method to do so. Like below:

```
old_record = Model.find(params[:id])
new_record = old_record.dup
new_record.save
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like

```
new_data = old_data.dup
new_data.save
```

Reference doc http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup